# Firebase functions - Counting children and updating an entry

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have been trying to use Firebase Functions to write a simple method, but I am unfamiliar with JS.

Below is the structure of my Realtime Database

> -spots
>
> ---is_hidden: false
>
> ---likes
>
> ------like_id_1: true
>
> ---dislikes
>
> ------dislike_id_1: true

I am trying to write a simple method that does the following: Whenever an entry is added to dislikes, count the likes and the dislikes.

> If the number of dislikes is larger than the number of ( likes + 5 ),
>   change the value of is_hidden to true

This is my attempt to solving the problem

```
exports.checkHiddenStatus = functions.database.ref('/spots/{spotid}').onWrite(
    (change, context) => {
      const collectionRef = change.after.ref;
      const isHiddenRef = collectionRef.child('is_hidden');
      const likesRef = collectionRef.child('likes');
      const dislikesRef = collectionRef.child('dislikes');


      if(isHiddenRef.before.val()) return;

      let likeCount = likesRef.numChildren();
      let dislikeCount = dislikesRef.numChildren();

      let isHidden = false;

      if( dislikeCount >= (likeCount + 5))
          isHidden = true;

      if(!isHidden) return;

      // Return the promise from countRef.transaction() so our function
      // waits for this async event to complete before it exits.
      return isHiddenRef.transaction((current) => {
        return isHidden;
      }).then(() => {
        return console.log('Counter updated.');
      });
    });
```

Sadly, because I have no experience with JS I keep getting stuck with error messages I don't understand. The most recent being

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined
>       at exports.checkHiddenStatus.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/user_code/index.js:28:28)

Can somebody please help me write this function? Thank you!

Comment: FYI the error message is saying that the problem is on line 28 of index.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to treat a database [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference) object like a Change object.  Change has `before` and `after` properties, but a reference does not.

If you have a database reference object, and you want the value of the database at that location, you need to query it with its [once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#once) method.

Read more about [reading](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) and [writing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data) data using the Admin SDK.